# Downloading a file from a subdirectory retains the subdirectory name

Tags: c#, asp.net, download

I am downloading a file through a C# ASPX page.  The file is passed in the URL File parameter in the form **temp\GUID\file.zip**.  My code:

```
   void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
       {
           if (Request.QueryString["File"] != null)
           {
               Response.BufferOutput = true;
               if (Request.QueryString["File"].Contains( "zip" ))
                   Response.ContentType = "application/zip"; //varies depending on the file being streamed
               Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + Request.QueryString["File"] + "\"" );
               Response.WriteFile( Server.MapPath( Request.QueryString["File"] ) );
           }
       }
   }
```

The problem is, the file appears in my Downloads directory as `tempguidfile` (ex: **temp07e315af-13c6-4537-92df-fae95cc0039fFile.zip**).  How do I get either `Response.Writefile()`, `TransmitFile()`, or something similar to save the file in the Downloads directory simply as **File.zip**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the line:

`Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + Request.QueryString["File"] + "\"" );`

Remove `Request.QueryString["File"]` and put your own file name.

Comment: /me pushes the DUH button.

Comment: My actual implementation:  I passed the file name as a separate parameter via `Path.GetFileName()`, and used `Request.QueryString["Filename"]` for the filename header.